# SharePoint 2010 List items - visual filtering based on timeline and other attributes?

Tags: 2010, list-view, filter, view

I am trying to design a visual filter & View for a standard Sharepoint List. Something similar to this one: http://www.aoglobalview.com/#/regulation-timeline/Clearing/global

- Each List Item has 4 distinct phases; of course the start & end date of these phases are different for each item
- When the user slides the Timeline Slider at the bottom, the View should be updated accordingly
- When the user stretches the Timeline Slider (done using the Zoom Out button in the above sample), additional items whose phases fall in the Timeline window, may be displayed.
- Additional filters like the buttons at the top: Global, EU, UK, US, etc.,

How can I build such a filter + display? Can I start with any of the existing Views (for e.g Gantt chart or Calendar View?)  Or use Visio to design?

Comment: Unfortunately this question was closed and I could not add an answer; so adding a comment.  

After quite a bit of R&D, I chose to incorporate this Timeline widget in a custom webpart: http://www.simile-widgets.org/wiki/Timeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's unreasonably hard if not impossible at all to create such functionality by modifying of standard list view. If you want to implement such an interactive asynchronously updated "view" you have to create custom webpart. And maybe it will be reasonable to find some third party timeline components in ASP.NET/Silverlight/Flash to save some efforts. Note that your interactive demo primer is created with Flash.

And there's another detail. Any list view is just a webpart page with ListViewWebPart and some other hidden webparts. So you can create new view and modify it's page to add your custom webpart instead of standart ListViewWebPart but such a modification will remove view change dropdown from that page breadcrumb navigation area. I don't know is there any way to fix it.